# ¿Por qué no imprime 5 veces el mensaje?

Tags: c

Una consulta si me pueden ayudar, estoy practicando lenguaje C usando CodeBlocks como IDE, pero estoy notando algo raro al tratar de compilar los ejercicios de práctica.

Para ver si está todo correctamente configurado, escribí un "Hola Mundo" simple para ver si se muestra el resultado en la consola y así fue. Ahora probando una sentencia "for" para escribir "Hola Mundo" 5 veces, la consola no me muestra el resultado. Compila correctamente pero la consola no muestra los 5 "Hola Mundo", solamente se ve el texto que dice "Process Returned 0".

El codigo de ejemplo es este:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    for(int i=1; i==5; i++)
    {
        printf("Hola Mundo");
    };
}
```

Tengo configurado como compilador MinGW GNU GCC Compiler. ¿Hay alguna configuración adicional que tenga que hacer? Estuve googleando pero no logré dar con la solución.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La condición de salida del bucle for está mal planteada:

```c
for(int i=1; i==5; i++)
```

La variable inicial que tiene la variable `i` es `1` y obviamente no será igual a `5`, por lo tanto, el resultado de la condición daría `false`, provocando que el bucle for no haga ninguna iteración.

Sí quieres imprimir `5` veces el `Hola Mundo` debes usar el operador `<=` en la condición del bucle:

```c
for(int i=1; i <= 5; i++)
```

**Observaciones:**

**1.-** Según el estándar, la función `main` debe retornar un valor de tipo `int`.

**2.-** La llave de cierre del bucle for no necesita llevar un punto y coma.

**3.-** Si el bucle for solo tiene una instrucción, no hace falta las llaves.

Siguiendo con las observaciones el código quedaría así:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

//El "void" indica que la función NO acepta argumentos.
int main(void)
{
    for(int i=1; i <= 5; i++)
        printf("Hola Mundo");
    return 0;
}
```

> > ¿Hay alguna configuración adicional que tenga que hacer?

No tiene nada que ver la configuración. Si no salió el resultado esperado fue por un [error lógico](https://techlib.net/definition/logic_error.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación en los errores que cometí, los tendré en cuenta para la próxima vez. Probé el código con los cambios y funciono.